# Why do we need footer, nav elements when we can use div

Tags: html, css

I am very new to HTML, so my question might be lame , pardon me for that. I created layout for my first site and noticed that I can use just **< div >** tag to create my footer, it is not mandatory to use **< footer >** tag for footer. It does not make any difference. So, I have question like "what exactly the case where **< footer >** has advantage over just **< div >** tag.(there must be some advantage and that is why it is in HTML). Same thing I found for **< article >** tag , without **< article >** tag, I could create the content page by just using **< div >** tag. Anyone could please explain me why do we really need footer and article (and all such element ) ?

Thanks for the help. I really appreciate.

Comment: Clarity as far as I know

Comment: It's semantic HTML5.

Comment: Might find the official spec worth reading: http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/dom.html#semantics-0

Answer (score 10, accepted):

HTML5 Elements such as article, header, footer, main, aside and many more are used for semantics - to add meaning to your code. It's easier for a person to read and edit the code when you know that the element is used as a header for example.

ARIA attributes can also be used in conjunction with these elements to provide even more meaning for screen readers and further accessibility.

Answer (score 2):

A basic explanation:

Simply all your links scattered in your web-pages may not be navigation. They can stay in a simple `<a href=''..>**</a>` . Links wrapped in `nav` denote major navigational links of webpages. Similarly footer denotes footer links.

Using these tags are helpful for screen readers, keeps our code clean, semantic, and compatible with modern browser as well. `Nav, footer, articles and section etc` are HTML5 standardization of a DIV element.

Further, it is easier to select those tags for designing without using any extra classes as we used frequently earlier (may be still using). For example, we can select `footer` just by `footer{..} , nav{..}` etc. instead `<div class="footer"> or div class="nav">`.

Answer (score 0):

`footer`, `article`, `header` and other new html5 tags are there to help you structure your page in a more comprehensive and natural way.
It will be a lot more easier to handle when you will use CSS code to format it.
You can, of course, use `div` tags with `id` or `class` attributes instead but your code will be clearer with those new tags.
I guess it might also be useful for Search Engines that analyzes the content of your pages.

Answer (score 0):

Besides helping making your code easier to read for humans, this and the othee new tags can make your website work better with automated tools like browser extensions which need to identify relevant parts of your code. Think a social plugin which wants to share an article, for instance.